# How can I improve an opinion based question?

Tags: discussion

I first stumbled across a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238828/what-is-the-best-biome-to-spawn-in-minecraft) that was about Minecraft biomes. This question was very poor, and was asking what the best biome was. I knew that this should be closed, but it wasn't a bad question underneath. If one specified what they needed for a good biome, the question would have been okay.

I first tried to edit some good biome requirements into the question. Of course, my edit was rejected as "too major".

I then asked it as a [separate question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238942/is-there-a-biome-with-adequate-resources-to-build-my-luxury-resort) that went something like this:

> Minecraft is awesome and cool and amazing, but I would like to know what biome is best to spawn in. I can't build if it takes a full day to traverse one. Often, I just give up. Now, I only play on worlds with a good spawn biome.
>
> This also could help me with picking out seeds for downloading maps, and is based on several factors:
>
> Temples. Desert temples, Jungle temples, all sorts of temples that can be raided for more materials.
>
> Villages. Villages are useful for, again, raiding, trading, and "borrowing" farms.
>
> Building space. Some biomes, such as jungles, have no space to build.
>
> Monsters. Some biomes have little visibility and is impossible to maneuver around, to avoid monsters.
>
> Materials. A land with lava, water, seeds, loot is a must for building and living on.
>
> Is there a biome I'm describing?

Of course, my question was closed as "Primarily Opinion Based."

In the comments, I asked how I could fix it, receiving answers but not enough to save the question.

How can I save this question?

Comment: So, none of the comments have actually been for the purpose of how to fix it for reopening. There has been comments on how to be less-opinion based, but these comments also point out that it is still a bad question. There are comments along the lines of "this can never be on topic, drop it", and there have been comments on how your requests are not necessarily realistic. This question has remained closed, **after several edits**. It is worth considering that just because you thought this was a good question, it may not be what the community thinks.

Comment: **Is there a way to fix this question?** I probably end up deleting the question, but this has gone on **too long.** I need answers, and the question has been gathering dust and downvotes.

Comment: At the end of the day, if its base is opinion, its primarily opinion. If you need answers, I would recommend asking in chat, or on a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really do not think this is salvageable. In part, because your entire premise is flawed. No one biome is going to have everything you want. There is ultimately no way you are going to avoid long walks to get to the things you need/want. Also in part because your requirements for a desirable biome are rather vague.

**Materials**:

- Lava? can occur anywhere, and if you spend a decent amount of time mining, you'll almost certainly encounter more than enough for your needs, and once you can reliably explore the nether, there is even MORE.
- Water occurs practically everywhere that isn't a desert, and even then, there's likely rivers somewhere near the edges. All you need is two bucket fulls placed in the corners of a 2x2 square, and you have an infinite source of water wherever you need it.
- Seeds: as you flatten/clear any dirt-based ground for building, you are likely to get some seeds from the tall grass - this is enough to start a small farm that can easily grow exponentially. Specific seeds like watermellon/pumpkin are more iffy, but wander enough and you'll find some.
- Do you care what type of wood you get for building? either way, all you need to find is one tree of the desired type, and collect some saplings.
- Loot: What kind of loot are you talking about? Most of the underground stuff doesn't really depend on the biome.

**Monsters**:
 Ok, this one's fairly straight-forward, you'd mostly want to avoid the dense jungles and dark-oak woods, and maybe some of the more mountainous terrain.

**Building space**:
Again, this ones a bit vague, if you are looking for flat land to build on - and of the savannas, deserts, or the various plains will likely do. But once you clear out some trees, some forests will also do the trick - you're going to need wood anyway. But is building on a flat area what you want? You can builds some impressive things on/in/around mountains...

**Villages/Temples**:
These are a bit more specific, but have other problems. We can suggest a biome with either a temple or or village... But there is no guarantee that when you start in that biome it will *have* the desired village/temple.

---

### Conclusions:

It doesn't matter where you start, there is no one best biome to start in. You are ultimately going to have to do a lot of walking to find what you want. And in many cases, when you find what you want, you can bring it to **where** you want. So your starting location doesn't really matter.

If you need to find a location with many nearby features, you don't need a starting biome, you need a tool like [MineAtlas](http://mineatlas.com/) that will either take your existing world's level.dat or a world generation seed and show you locations of villages and temples, and where to go to get at specific biomes that have the resources you need - rather than wandering aimlessly.

A good starting biome is far too subjective, unless you have a ***very specific*** list of requirements, and even then it is largely pointless as every instance of a biome can vary in its usefulness. What you want are SEEDS that have previously been checked out by other users... Unfortunately, I believe this avenue of questioning has also been determined to be ogff-topic - But there are other resources on the net to find what you are looking for like [Minecraft-Seeds.net](http://minecraft-seeds.net)

Comment: This would actually be a good answer for the main question.

Comment: @RainbowDash Except that the answer is essentially, "Any biome at all, except desert".  The point that's being made is that what you're asking isn't an actual, objective question.  There's nothing there that can be answered in Arqade's QA format.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted this question. At the end of the day, it *was* opinion based, and it has not received any positive attention.